# Eliminate or reduce lag when moving Rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, rigid-bodies

I'm working on a Multiplayer shooter in Unity. It uses Rigidbodies for interactable items like weapons. We base that code on a modified version of this repo

https://github.com/TomorrowTodayLabs/NewtonVR

The relevant code is

```
protected override void FixedUpdate()
{
    base.FixedUpdate();

    if (IsAttached == true)
    {
        Vector3 PositionDelta;
        Quaternion RotationDelta;

        float angle;
        Vector3 axis;

        if (InteractionPoint != null)
        {
            RotationDelta = AttachedHand.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(InteractionPoint.rotation);
            PositionDelta = (AttachedHand.transform.position - InteractionPoint.position);
        }
        else
        {
            RotationDelta = PickupTransform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(this.transform.rotation);
            PositionDelta = (PickupTransform.position - this.transform.position);
        }

        RotationDelta.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);

        if (angle > 180)
            angle -= 360;

        if (angle != 0)
        {
            Vector3 AngularTarget = (Time.fixedDeltaTime * angle * axis) * AttachedRotationMagic;
            this.Rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.Rigidbody.angularVelocity, AngularTarget, 10f);
        }

        Vector3 VelocityTarget = PositionDelta * AttachedPositionMagic * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        this.Rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.Rigidbody.velocity, VelocityTarget, 10f);
    }
}
```

The benefit of using Rigidbodies is that you get collision detection with wall, floors and other rigid bodies. This is crucial in a Multiplayer game, you do not want players to cheat by pushing weapons through walls and shoot people. Problem is it introduces a lot of latency between the weapon and the Vive controller. So much its hard to aim, you need to wait until the rigidbody catches up with the controller. 
Any good way of solving this and keep collision detection?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: We parent the item to the Vive controller, but it introduces a lot of other problems